# How can a paragraph be changed to wrap at a column greater than that at which it currently wraps?

Tags: vim, emacs, paragraph, geany

I've got many paragraphs of the following form (shown in the Geany text editor):

[image]

The text wraps at column 48 currently. I want it to wrap at column 80. On the right is shown a vertical line indicating column 80.

How can this text (which is actually a small selection of a great deal of text) be selected and reformatted such that it wraps at column 80 (preferably preserving the leading whitespace of 8 spaces — though this is not particularly important). I am happy to see solutions in Geany, Vim or Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

1. `vim file.txt`
2. type `:set textwidth=72`
3. type `V` to start highlighting
4. type `G` to go to the bottom of the file
5. type `gq` to break the line at 72 character
6. type `g` to go back to the top
7. type `V` to start highlighting
8. type `G` to go the bottom
9. type `>` to indent the text
10. repeat 5-8 until indented properly